# ContextJS action with object id that I have clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use ContextJs to display right-click context menu and I want to remove object I clicked on using right mouse button. I've used this code:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

to remove div object I clicked on. But now I have context menu which shows up when I click over this div (I use selectors in context.attach property to display menu only when I click over this div).And I don't know how to remove my div, because

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

removes my "remove" label in context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Context.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Context.js) isn't currently able to give you an HTML element on which you've performed a right click action. But you can modify the plugin to do that for you, as discussed in [this pull request](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Context.js/pull/6#issuecomment-48340626) and then use it like this:

```
{
    text: 'Menu item',
    action: function (e, clickedElement) { ... }
}
```